# How to insert a component inside innerhtml content in angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am rendering html content from Django backend using

```
[innerHtml]="blog_Data.contents"
```

But because I want to insert another component like (subscription box/ content recommendation) in between the content of all the blogs.

I want to know if there is any method, without manually inserting everything on the backend.

I want a global solution for this, which automatically insert subscription box in between the content.

For example I am attaching a reference screenshot of Yourstory's content:

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Try Content Projection - https://angular.io/guide/content-projection

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Content Projection from Angular itself or use a server-side rendering from the backend of the content, something like WordPress shortcodes.